# VB.Net XMLTextReader Keeps Skipping 1st Element in Children

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this... I am reading an XML file created from the server and all is good except that when I try to process the file it's always skipping one of the first child elements.  And when I run a test with no processing, just a straight reader and looping through the elements, the 1st element is there.  But as soon as I add a check to see if the node is an Element, it skips an "Attachment" element.  Here's my XML:

```
<Reports xmlns="">
<FinalReport JobID="335417" LineItemID="400391" FileNumber="AGAINTEST" PropertyID="98765312" PONumber="" PropAddress="9255 John Street" PropCity="Fairfax" PropState="VA" PropZip="22132" OrderStatus="Delivered" ServiceName="Ext Property Inspection">
    <DataCapture>
        <!--Report saved: 7/1/2011 11:28:43 AM by: frank-->
        <report>
            <StreetVisible>No</StreetVisible>
            <Vacant>No</Vacant>
            <SaleSign>No</SaleSign>
            <RentSign>No</RentSign>
            <ExtCondition>Average</ExtCondition>
            <ComparedCondition>Similar</ComparedCondition>
            <DeferredMaintenance>No</DeferredMaintenance>
            <UnderConstruction>No</UnderConstruction>
            <SafetyIssues>No</SafetyIssues>
            <NaturalDisaster>No</NaturalDisaster>
            <PropertyLocation>Gated</PropertyLocation>
            <PropertyUse>Triplex</PropertyUse>
            <Nonresidential>No</Nonresidential>
            <Outbuildings>Shed</Outbuildings>
            <Garage>No</Garage>
            <Carport>No</Carport>
            <Capacity>2</Capacity>
            <AdverseFactors>Railroad</AdverseFactors>
            <PositiveFactors>GolfCourse</PositiveFactors>
            <PropertyType>CondoGarden</PropertyType>
            <HomeFront>Yes</HomeFront>
            <AddressPhoto>Yes</AddressPhoto>
            <StreetScene>Yes</StreetScene>
            <AnyComments>Test some comments here...</AnyComments>
            <FieldRepName>JOE INSPECTIONS</FieldRepName>
        </report>
    </DataCapture>
    <Attachment imageID="1988" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
    <Attachment imageID="1990" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
    <Attachment imageID="1991" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
    <Attachment imageID="1992" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
    <Attachment imageID="1993" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
    <Attachment imageID="1994" extension="jpg" image_type="IMG" Keyed="0" ImageNote="" Image="Base64" />
</FinalReport>
<PDFReport>Base64</PDFReport>
```

And Here's the code that I'm using to get the XML - I I remove everything between the `reader.Read()`, Then this 1st "Attachment" element seems to show up.  I've even tried removing the `If reader.IsStartElement()` and still no luck.

```
Using reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(xdoc.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Document, Nothing)

                        Dim xData As New OrderResults_Class

                        While reader.Read()

                            If reader.IsStartElement() Then
                                LogDebug.Append(vbCrLf & "Row: " & x & " Is Start: " & reader.IsStartElement() & " Node Type: " & reader.NodeType() & " Element: " & reader.Name & " >> Attributes: " & reader.HasAttributes.ToString & " Value: " & Left(reader.Value, 100))
                                ele = reader.Name

                                Select Case ele
                                    Case "Attachment"
                                        'LogDebug.Append(vbCrLf & "Row: (" & a & ") " & x & " Node Type: " & reader.NodeType() & " Element: " & reader.Name & " >> Attributes: " & reader.HasAttributes.ToString & " Value: " & Left(reader.Value, 100))
                                        If reader.HasAttributes Then
                                            Dim xDataImg As New NVMSOrderResults_Images_Class

                                            Dim myImage() As Byte = ConvertImageFromBase64(reader.GetAttribute("Image"))

                                            With xDataImg
                                                .JobID = CheckOrder
                                                .ImageRef = reader.GetAttribute("imageID")
                                                .FileNumber = rs("FileNumber").ToString
                                                .ImageDescription = reader.GetAttribute("ImageNote")
                                                .ImageType = reader.GetAttribute("extension")
                                                .ImageFile = myImage
                                            End With

                                            Dim ImgRet As String = Process_OrderResults_Images(xDataImg)
                                            If IsNumeric(ImgRet) Then
                                                LogMsg = "[" & rs("FileNumber").ToString & "] Photo Received: " & ImgRet
                                            Else
                                                LogMsg = "[" & reader.GetAttribute("imageID") & "] Error processing photo: " & ImgRet
                                            End If
                                            AppLogging.WriteTableLog(CheckOrder, LogMsg)
                                        End If

                                    Case "FinalReport"
                                        If reader.HasAttributes Then
                                            With xData
                                                .JobID = CheckOrder
                                                .LineItemID = reader.GetAttribute("LineItemID")
                                                .FileNumber = reader.GetAttribute("FileNumber")
                                                .PropertyID = reader.GetAttribute("PropertyID")
                                                .PropAddress = reader.GetAttribute("PropAddress")
                                                .PropCity = reader.GetAttribute("PropCity")
                                                .PropState = reader.GetAttribute("PropState")
                                                .PropZip = reader.GetAttribute("PropZip")
                                                .Service = reader.GetAttribute("ServiceName")
                                            End With
                                            'LogDebug.Append(vbCrLf & "Row: (" & i & ") " & x & " Node Type: " & reader.NodeType() & " Element: " & reader.Name & " >> Attributes: " & reader.HasAttributes.ToString & " Value: " & Left(reader.Value, 100))
                                        End If

                                    Case "DataCapture"
                                        xData.DataCollection = reader.ReadInnerXml

                                End Select
                            ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Attribute Then
                                LogDebug.Append(vbCrLf & "This is an Attib: " & ele & " Is Start: " & reader.IsStartElement() & " Node Type: " & reader.NodeType() & " Element: " & reader.Name & " >> Attributes: " & reader.HasAttributes.ToString & " Value: " & Left(reader.Value, 100))
                            ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then
                                If ele = "PDFReport" Then
                                    xData.PDFReport = ConvertImageFromBase64(reader.Value)

                                    'Save Order Results ///////////////////////////
                                    Dim ResultRet As String = Process_OrderResults(xData)
                                    If IsNumeric(ResultRet) Then
                                        LogMsg = "[" & rs("FileNumber").ToString & "] Job Successfully Received: " & CheckOrder
                                    Else
                                        LogMsg = "[" & rs("FileNumber").ToString & "] Error processing results: " & ResultRet
                                    End If
                                    AppLogging.WriteTableLog(CheckOrder, LogMsg)
                                End If
                            End If

                            x += 1

                        End While

                        '// Write Debugging Text ////////////////////////////////////////////
                        AppLogging.WriteTableLog(CheckOrder, LogDebug.ToString)

                        y += 1
                    End Using
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something... I'm getting tired of looking at this code ;D
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XmlTextReader is documented as "forward only"; 
My personal interpretation of this would mean that if you have attributes x=1 y=2 z=3
and try to use getattribute("y") then you skip over attribute "x" and cannot get back to it - the attributes are not a hashlist as such but a foward searched string buffer

so if you have one attribute missing from an input dataset (or in the wrong order) doesn't this mean that you will skip forward to the next element - I haven't tested this properly but seems to match behaviour of code I've written (and then re-written corretcly)

just my 2-penneth; I may be wrong - I may be heading in the right direction but not there yet - just trying to help